# Apache cannot detect and rewrite URLs to lowercase

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, lowercase, rewritemap

***What am I trying to achieve?***

I want to convert all URL's that are within the **/migrate** directory (and subdirectories) to lowercase.

***What have I done?***

I have migrated my website from DNN to Wordpress.  Therefore I have URL's in my posts that reference images with a combination of upper and lowercase letters.

All of my directories and files on disk in the **/migrate** folder (and subfolders) are lowercase.

When I view an article, if the reference to the image has an uppercase character, I am getting a 404 which is expected.

For example:

https://xxx.domain.net/wp-content/migrate/ABC/image.jpg

https://xxx.domain.net/wp-content/migrate/Xyz/image.jpg

https://xxx.domain.net/wp-content/migrate/abc/Image.jpg

https://xxx.domain.net/wp-content/migrate/ABC/Xyz/image.jpg

So after reading various articles online and on here I tried a few things:

1) Enabled mod_speling and added this to apache2.conf

```
LoadModule speling_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_speling.so
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling On
CheckCaseOnly On
</IfModule>
```

This didn't work, continued to get 404's.

2) Tired to use Rewritemap in my /etc/sites-enabled/mysite.conf file.

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /migrate [A-Z]
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

However this would rewrite **all** URL's to lowercase and it broke some of the Wordpress plugins and editors as the files on disk had uppercase characters.

My .htaccess file in the Wordpress root directory is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

#BEGIN Wordpress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours and hours of trying different things and reading through the logs, I have worked this out!

Basically I needed to ignore all the other Wordpress directories from rewriting.

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/uploads/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/themes/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/plugins/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-includes/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```